# Blank activity in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to create a basic google map activity, but when i try to run it to my smartphone, I get a blank activity (click [here](http://postimg.org/image/6hr5qlwhf) to see a screenshot of the issue). What im doing wrong? It is something wrong with my API Key, maybe?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fa2015.mapstest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="_MyKey_"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        } }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post links to images on external websites. The images might get taken offline, rendering your post useless to all people coming here in the future..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem usually happens when there is some problem with the wy you defined Google Maps permissions or from a bad configuration of the allowed API in the Google API console.

Make sure that you turn on the Google Maps Version 2 for Android in the console and not the one for web. Also please check your permission, here's a related SO ticket which encounter blank screen: [Android Google Map API V2 Blank Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761245/android-google-map-api-v2-blank-screen)

Here's a sample demo app for Google Maps Android API v2: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples

Comment: Thanks! that was really useful

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have enabled the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://console.developers.google.com).

Then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761878/4924793) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30559898/4924793).

Comment: This answer is not useful

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing out the API key. 
I assume that you use android studio (maps activity). After creating a project , you have to create an API key for your project and that needs to be linked in the project.
To create an API key, you have to visit a link provided in google_maps_api.xml (from your project).

Once you created your API key, then you have to insert that API key in the google_maps_api.xml file (may be the in last line where asks for your key).

[Follow this pic for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Xri.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had same Problem. To solve it you need to check your permissions

To do this:

1. Go to the google cloud console
2. Go to the *Enable APIs and Services* section
3. Enable the [*Google Maps Android API*](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/maps-android-backend.googleapis.com/)

Answer (score 0):

After following this [Map With Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker) still I was getting blank screen. Then you need to again re-create the new API KEY and also enable MAPS SDK for Android.
Then you need to restrict your key for specific use mentioning platform and API Restriction.