# Google map api showing blank map in android

Tags: android, api, dictionary, direction

I am using google map direction api and my api key is on **billing mode**.When I try to use this map API..It works only on one device(When I installed it for the first time).
I am unable to use it on any other device.My map becomes blank.
**Free trial** api's works fine!!

Comment: issue with your api key

Comment: Possible duplicate of :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761878/7319704

Comment: free trial works ..

Answer (score 1):

Please give the permissions with your manifest. First, in the following you need to replace the package name with your package.

```
 <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

per your package name, should be --

```
<permission
          android:name="com.example.barcodelibrary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.barcodelibrary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Finally, you seem to be missing the following permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible

1.Please change your api key and check it.

2.Otherwise, you have to build an apk from which android studio id you give to get api key from android google map.