# blank map while using places api key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using the google places API ( payment activated ) I get the key, when added it to my application the search works well, but, the map itself not working it shows blank and below I can see the google logo

my XML

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and my java code for declare the places API & map

```
    private void initMapsAndPlaces() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        Places.initialize(this, mApiKey);
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                startSearch(text.toString(), true, null, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
                if (buttonCode == MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_BACK) {
                    materialSearchBar.disableSearch();
                    materialSearchBar.clearSuggestions();
                }
            }
        });

        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest predictionsRequest = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                        .setCountry(mCountry)
                        .setSessionToken(token)
                        .setQuery(s.toString())
                        .build();
                placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(predictionsRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse predictionsResponse = task.getResult();
                            if (predictionsResponse != null) {
                                predictionList = predictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions();
                                List<String> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < predictionList.size(); i++) {
                                    AutocompletePrediction prediction = predictionList.get(i);
                                    suggestionsList.add(prediction.getFullText(null).toString());
                                }
                                materialSearchBar.updateLastSuggestions(suggestionsList);
                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (!materialSearchBar.isSuggestionsVisible()) {
                                            materialSearchBar.showSuggestionsList();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "prediction fetching task unSuccessful");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        materialSearchBar.setSuggestionsClickListener(new SuggestionsAdapter.OnItemViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClickListener(int position, View v) {
                if (position >= predictionList.size()) {
                    return;
                }
                AutocompletePrediction selectedPrediction = predictionList.get(position);
                String suggestion = materialSearchBar.getLastSuggestions().get(position).toString();
                materialSearchBar.setText(suggestion);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        materialSearchBar.clearSuggestions();
                    }
                }, 1000);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(materialSearchBar.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                }

                String placeId = selectedPrediction.getPlaceId();
                List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS);

                FetchPlaceRequest fetchPlaceRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields).build();
                placesClient.fetchPlace(fetchPlaceRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
                        Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
                        Log.i(TAG, "place found " + place.getName() + place.getAddress());
                        LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                        if (latLng != null) {
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                        }

                        rippleBg.startRippleAnimation();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                rippleBg.stopRippleAnimation();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                                    apiException.printStackTrace();
                                    int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                                    Log.i(TAG, "place not found" + e.getMessage());
                                    Log.i(TAG, "status code : " + statusCode);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void OnItemDeleteListener(int position, View v) {
            }
        });
    }
```

permissions are added

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

can anyone help me, please?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761878/12478830

Comment: ty u saved my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone still suffering

after a long time of the search, I missed adding

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/places_api_key" />
```

to manifest file.